# How does parent process of GenServer wait for its response?

Tags: elixir

There is an agent-like implementation from the official Elixir guide

```
defmodule AAgent do
  def start_agent do
    spawn_link fn -> loop(%{}) end
  end

  def loop(state \\ %{}) do
    receive do
      {:put, key, value, caller} ->
        new_state = Map.put(state, key, value)
        send caller, new_state
        loop(new_state)
      {:get, key, caller} ->
        send caller, Map.get(state, key)
        loop(state)
    end
  end
end
```

When it's used, the response is passed to its caller process mailbox

```
a = AAgent.start_agent
send a, {:put, :a, 42, self()}
flush
%{a: 42}
```

However, when an actual agent is used (which internally uses `GenServer`), the response is available to the parent process right away

```
iex> Agent.get(agent, fn list -> list end)
["eggs"]
```

I don't need to write a `receive` block to get `["eggs"]` when I use agent, the result already available, even though it's a separate process that passed data to another process. Is it possible to achieve the same effect using  bare processes or does `GenServer` use something else under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't need to write a receive block to get ["eggs"] when I use agent, the result already available

You didn't write receive, but `Agent.get` indirectly does do a `receive` by calling `GenServer.call` which calls `:gen.call` [which contains the `receive`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/84be7e0ec7c0c64f1beb418cdd09879822aca4b0/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L169). You can implement the same for your Agent with just 4 lines of code:

```
defmodule AAgent do
  def start_agent do
    spawn_link fn -> loop(%{}) end
  end

  def loop(state \\ %{}) do
    receive do
      {:put, key, value, _caller} ->
        new_state = Map.put(state, key, value)
        loop(new_state)
      {:get, key, caller} ->
        send caller, Map.get(state, key)
        loop(state)
    end
  end

  def get(agent, key) do
    send(agent, {:get, key, self()})
    receive do x -> x end
  end
end

a = AAgent.start_agent
send a, {:put, :a, 42, self()}
IO.inspect AAgent.get(a, :a)
```

Output:

```
42
```

Answer (score 4):

The receive block is inside the `Agent.get/2` function - you don't need to write it manually. The underlying principle is exactly the same, though.